# Overview of Handler in GWT

Tags: gwt, handler

Is there an overview about all handlers and their corresponding containers in GWT? Whenever I try to add a handler to a container, I have to check, whether the handler fires an event or not (the JavaDoc does not provide useful information about this). For example a ResizeHandler:

```
       SplitLayoutPanel splitLayoutPanel = new SplitLayoutPanel() {
            @Override
            public void onResize() {
                super.onResize();
                System.out.println("onResize");
            }           
        };

        splitLayoutPanel.addHandler(new ResizeHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {

                System.out.println("resize");

            }
        }, ResizeEvent.getType());
```

Overwriting the onResize()-method (1. example) gives an information, if the splitter changes, but if I add a ResizeHandler (2. example), I do not get any call of the onResize-method. I don't understand why and don't find the documentation why the handler is not allowed in this container.

I search for an overview of all available handlers, together with their possible containers  and event, when they will be fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there will be a more specific `addHandler` method.  For example, `Button` has `addClickHandler(ClickHandler)`.  The interface that defines that method is `HasClickHandlers`, so you can look out for that, for example.

If the event doesn't have it's own `addXyzHandler` method, it probably won't be supported very well.  In that case, it's usually pretty easy to subclass the widget and add support for that handler yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a handler using addHandler() on a Widget, you have to ensure the underlying DOM element could catch matching event. If yes, you also have to tell your Widget to sink this event using

```
void com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.sinkEvents(int eventBitsToAdd)
```

where eventBitsToAdd is a constant from com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.
AFAIK ONRESIZE event is not yet supported natively. So as I said yesterday, you have to implement your mouse handlers and gesture, or override a slider ;-)